# Sharepoint 2010 - Displaying the Tag Path on every page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, tags

Basically I have many pages on a site which are tagged with various main tags and sub tags.

The tags are also used as the navigation tool to get to different pages.  I am wondering if it is possible to display the tag path on top of each path so the user knows exactly where they are.

For example, if I am in a page that is tagged under one sub-tag , It would display at the top:

`Name of Main Tag >> Name of Current Pages Tag`